# QImage rendering in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, qt5, subpixel-rendering

I want to run the application in ubuntu 22.04 that uses Qimage for rendering secondary window and opengl for primary window. when I launch the application, the application hangs & fps drops. After commenting the Qimage rendering part for secondary window, Application runs without fps drop. Please help me out these. Thanks in advance.